# Packages imported as normal folders in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to import a project in Eclipse. The other person working on this project uses IntelliJ.
The project is a Maven one, but when I import it using the `File > Import > Existing Maven Project` menu, the packages in src are displayed as normal folders, and I get errors saying that the package definition in the java files are wrong.

I tried to import the project as a normal Java project (by creating a new Java project and changing the default location), but I get the same result.

I tried to look for other .project files that might conflict with my version of Eclipse, but there is none.

I tried to delete every file related to IntelliJ, but it did not change anything.

I also tried to remove the .metadata directory of my Eclipse workspace and then import the project again, but still got the same result.

Finally, I tried to run the commands `mvn eclipse:clean` and `mvn eclipse:eclipse` but nothing changed.

There is a `.classpath` file in the project, so I don't see why the packages are not recognized as pasckages.

I am now out of option and completely stuck until I figure this out.

Comment: Does the project have multiple modules? Is the folder-structure a regular one using `src/main/java`?

Comment: There is only one module. The packages are directly under src.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the usual Maven convention.